# moviepy записывает битые видеофайлы с кодеком h264

Tags: python-3.x, moviepy

В коде я указал что хочу использовать последнюю версию ffmpeg

```
change_settings({"FFMPEG_BINARY": r"C:\Program Files\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"})
```

ffmpeg version 6.0-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)

Вот мой moviepy:

```
PS D:\projects\creepy_parse_2.0> pip show moviepy
Name: moviepy
Version: 1.0.3
```

Я монтирую не самый сложный на свете ролик, несколько "crossfadeout", несколько crossfadein, немного "CompositeVideoClip", чуть больше concatenate_videoclips.

Сначала получаю три коротких ролика потом комбинацию их немного между собой, и в результате получаю желаемые два ролика.

Вот финальная часть скрипта:

```
t = VideoFileClip(a.title.video)
s = VideoFileClip(a.story.video)
e = VideoFileClip(a.end.video)
short = concatenate_videoclips([s, e])
short.write_videofile(shorts_folder, **preset_video)
sh = VideoFileClip(shorts_folder)
full = concatenate_videoclips([t, sh])
full.write_videofile(full_path, **preset_video)
```

Вот настройки для записи видео

```
preset_video = {"fps": 30,
            "preset": "fast",
            "codec": "h264_nvenc",
            "threads": 4,
            "bitrate": '9000k',
            "audio_codec": 'aac',
            "audio_bitrate": '64k',
            "audio_fps": 22050,
            "verbose": True,
            "logger": 'bar'}
```

(я хочу именно h264 кодек, пробовал другие его типы результат один)

Вот информация о файле который я получил

```
Video: MPEG4 Video (H264) 720x1280 30fps 8718kbps [V: h264 high 4:4:4 predictive L3.2, gbrp, 720x1280, 8718 kb/s]
    Audio: AAC 22050Hz stereo 64kbps [A: SoundHandler (aac lc, 22050 Hz, stereo, 64 kb/s)]
```

Первое что я заметил когда смотрел видео на десктопе, видео нельзя нормально перематывать, я могу перематывать ролик только на конкретные точки, которых примерно пять на весь таймлайн, пробовал в нескольких плеерах...

А во вторых, когда я скидываю видео в телеграмм он не может его воспроизвести, вижу сообщение "App was unable to play this video..."
Приложу скрин.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С файлом явно что то не так, как мне записать нормальный видео ролик?

Comment: https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/560